# “causing” vs “that ... caused”

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

"The accident happened on 1st April causing many casualties." or "The accident that happened on 1st April caused many casualties."

- I was just wondering if the modifier in the sentence could be in an ing-form, if not how can explain why not?

Comment: In the US at least, it’d be more common to say, “happened on the first of April...” or “happened on April 1st”  or in more business lingo “happened on 1-April”

Comment: I’ve edited the title of your question so that it’s more specific to your question. Feel free to edit further.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct.   What counts as a modifier changes.

> The accident happened on 1st April, causing many casualties.

Here, the finite verb "happened" forms a clause with "the accident" as its subject.   The participial phrase "causing many accidents" is a supplemental modifier, further describing the content of the entire clause.

> The accident that happened on 1st April caused many casualties.

Here, the finite verb "happened" forms a clause with "that" as its subject.   The restrictive relative clause "that happened on 1st April" further describes the noun phrase "the accident".   The finite verb "caused" forms a matrix clause, with the entire phrase "the accident that happened on 1st April" as its subject.

Comment: The comma is important, 1st of April doesn't usually cause casualties :) Strickly speaking though, "on 1st April" cannot take a participle, and "on" can't take a "participative noun", if that's what that is called.